# onProviderDisabled - differentiating the provider

Tags: android

```
public void getCurrentLocation(){

 final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         //
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            if(provider=="gps"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
            Log.i("lm_disabled",provider);
        }
      };

  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, locationListener);
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, locationListener);
}
```

This seems like a legit code. However, the if expression never runs. I have debugged my application, the provider is "gps", it is string type - but the if returns false, I guess...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do `provider.equals("gps")` in your if statement. In java, you have to compare strings using the `.equals()` method. In java, `==` checks to see if the two object references match, not if the strings are the same. For more information, see this [StackoverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839).

Comment: You should also use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER instead of "gps" since this may change in the future..